# Haskell - Safe and Trustworthy extensions

Tags: haskell

Looking at some code in `hackage` I stumbled upon the `Safe` and `Trustworthy` extensions.

What do they mean broadly (or also exactly...)? Is there a good rule of thumb on when to use them and when not?

Comment: `Safe` imposes a set of restructions on the language. For example not using `unsafeIO`, and only using other modules that are safe. It thus means that if you compile with safe, certain aspects that Haskell is supposed to guarantee are enforced, by making "tricks" to escape these impossible

Comment: `Trustworthy` on the other hand is a claim made by the author of the package that you can trust the package. Although this has *some* value, it does not really makes restrictions, so it is more some sort of "annotation" to the module.

Comment: thanks @WillemVanOnsem. So the good practice (and strictest one) when writing a new module would be to use the `Safe` pragma? If I have `Safe` declared, `Trustworthy` becomes redundant or does it make sense to use both?

Comment: well `Safe` is stronger than `Trustworthy`, so I think using both does not add much no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Safe Haskell* is in essence a subset of the Haskell language. It aims to disable certain "tricks" that are often used, like for example [**`unsafePerformIO :: IO a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafePerformIO), and furthermore it (aims to) guarantee that you do not somehow get access to private functions, data constructors, etc. of a module that aims to prevent access from these. In short *safe Haskell* guarantees three things:

1. *Referential transparency*;
2. *Module boundary control*; and
3. *Semantic consistency*.

A safe module has to follow these limitations, and furthermore only work with safe modules. A safe module of course does not mean that the code it works with is correct, or that an `IO` action for example can not be malicious. But it has some guarantees since if a function has a type that has no `IO`, then normally the module should not be able to perform `IO` in an unsafe way.

Certain extensions like `TemplateHaskell` and specifying `{-# RULES … #-}` pragma's are not allowed in safe Haskell. Other extensions, like `DeriveDataTypeable` are allowed, but only if one makes use of the `deriving` clause to generate an instance, and thus not generates a custom one.

Some modules however, *need* to make use of extensions in order to work properly. In that case, the author can mark the module as `Trustworthy`. That means that the *author* claims that the module exposes a *safe* API, but that it internally need to work with some unsafe extensions, pragmas, etc. The compiler thus can not guarantee safety.

These extensions are documented  in [the documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/safe-haskell.html#safe-trust):

> The Safe Haskell extension introduces the following three language
>   flags:
>
> - `XSafe` — Enables the **safe language dialect**, asking GHC to guarantee trust. The safe language dialect requires that all imports
>     be trusted or a compilation error will occur.
> - `XTrustworthy` — Means that while this module may invoke unsafe functions internally, the **module's author claims that it exports an
>     API that can't be used in an unsafe way**. This doesn't enable the
>     safe language or place any restrictions on the allowed Haskell code.
>     The trust guarantee is provided by the module author, not GHC. An
>     import statement with the safe keyword results in a compilation error
>     if the imported module is not trusted. An import statement without the
>     keyword behaves as usual and can import any module whether trusted or
>     not.
> - `XUnsafe` — Marks the module being compiled as unsafe so that modules compiled using -XSafe can't import it.